# API network request error on iOS device, not simulator

Tags: swift, api, networking, youtube-api

ok so i've been trying to get this problem figured out for 2 days now, hoping someone can help.

quick background, i’m making an api request for data. using a function that calls a service function i made. now everything works good on the first load, collectionview loads fine. at some point i run another call for more data. accept now i get a URL Error.
This doesn’t work on my iphone, but does work perfectly on simulator, so not sure what it could be.
heres the service function that makes the api request:

```
func fetchYoutubeData(interest: String, maxResult: Int, pageToken: String, completion: @escaping(Result<Youtube, WHError>) -> Void) {
    let urlString = baseYoutubeURL+interest+youtubeAPIKey+"&maxResults=\(maxResult)&pageToken=\(pageToken)"
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
      completion(.failure(.URLError))
      return
    }
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, error) in
      if let _ = error {
        completion(.failure(.DataError))
        return
      }
      guard let data = data else { return }
      do {
        let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Youtube.self, from: data)
        print(result)
        completion(.success(result))
      } catch {
        completion(.failure(.JSONError))
      }
    }
    task.resume()
  }
```

heres my controller function that calls service and handles the data on completion:

```
func fetchNewData(maxResult: Int, pageToken: String) {
    guard let interest   = self.interest.text else { return }
    print(pageToken)
    NetworkServices.shared.fetchYoutubeData(interest: interest, maxResult: maxResult, pageToken: pageToken) { [unowned self] (result) in
      switch result {
      case .success(let youtubeGroup):
        let items = youtubeGroup.items
        self.youtubeData.items.append(contentsOf: items)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.horizontalCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
      case .failure(let error):
        print("DOES GET ERROR")
        print(error)
      }
    }
  }
```

again it works perfectly on simulator, but not on my device, i can get first call to work, but after that, once i use pageToken to get more data, i get a URL Error.

any help would be seriously appreciated

Comment: It would help if you could provide the specific error message you are receiving.

Comment: @MikeTaverne, sure so it's just a custom error response. I've got a enum for handling networking errors. and the error comes at the guard statement when creating the URL from the urlString.
response is:
URLError: "Error with endpoint URL"
The operation couldn’t be completed. (Whats_Hunt.WHError error 0.)
0 being the selected enum index.
not sure if that's helpful to you. i wonder if it has to do with versions of iOS in Simulator vs my Device?

Comment: Hmm... that helps some. What is the URL string when it fails?

Comment: when i make my second request i add the pageToken, that's when the error happens. accept as I said it works when running on simulator, and when I put this URL in the browser, I get my data.

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&fields=prevPageToken,nextPageToken,items(id,snippet)&type=video&relevanceLanguage=en&order=relevance&q=iOS Development&key=MY_KEY&maxResults=48&pageToken=CDAQAA

not sure why it does that

Comment: @MikeTaverne you were right to look at the URL string, I had forgot to format the q string properly in the secondary call for data. not sure how to give you credit from a comment. otherwise I would

Comment: No worries, glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

so of course like alot of things , it's something small I missed. I'll keep the question here, incase someone finds themself in a similar situation.
the problem was in the first request I reformat the "interest" to remove spaces from the string and replace them with +. you need to do this for the Youtube API query string that you provide.
i did this in the first request, but for my query for additional data, I forgot to reformat the request in the separate call.
easy fix thankfully

Answer (score 0):

I added "App Transport Security Settings" to the Info.plist file then selected "Allow Arbitrary Loads" and set that value to "YES" and that worked. My assumption is that there was an issue with the security cert on the client development environment that was preventing the app from making calls over HTTPS.

And never fear, I only allow arbitrary loads in the dev and qa environments.